# Error in storing outer class object in inner class C++

Tags: c++11, inner-classes, circular-buffer

I was implementing the ring buffer and have encountered an error. What does it mean to store a reference of outer class(class ring) object(m_ring) in inner class(class iterator) and when I remove the reference(&) the program compiles correctly but crashes. Please explain what is happening.(See the comment in Ring.h) Sorry for bad English.

```
// Ring.h
#ifndef RING.H
#define RING.H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class ring {
    unsigned int m_size;
    int m_pos;
    T *m_values;
public:
    class iterator;
public:
    ring(unsigned int size) : m_size(size), m_pos(0)
    {
        m_values = new T[m_size];
    }
    ~ring()
    {
        delete[] m_values;
    }
    void add(const T &val)
    {
        m_values[m_pos] = val;
        m_pos++;
        m_pos %= m_size;
    }
    T& get(int pos)
    {
        return m_values[pos];
    }
    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator(0, *this);
    }
    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator(m_size, *this);
    }
};
template<class T>
class ring<T>::iterator {
    int m_pos;
    ring &m_ring;                              // Removing & gives garbage output.
public:
    iterator(int pos, ring& aRing) : m_pos(pos), m_ring(aRing){}
    bool operator!=(const iterator &other) const
    {
        return other.m_pos != m_pos;
    }
    iterator &operator++(int)
    {
        m_pos++;
        return *this;
    }
    iterator &operator++()
    {
        m_pos++;
        return *this;
    }
    T &operator*()
    {
       // return m_ring.m_values[m_pos];
        return m_ring.get(m_pos);
    }
};
#endif // RING
```

Driver program :

```
// Ring_Buffer_Class.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "ring.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ring<string> textring(3);
    textring.add("one");
    textring.add("two");
    textring.add("three");
    textring.add("four");
    // C++ 98
    for(ring<string>::iterator it = textring.begin(); it != textring.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    // C++11
    for(string value : textring)
    {
        cout << value << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I also observed that removing ~ring() (Destructor) results into correct output.

Expected output :

> four
>  
>   two
>  
>   three
>   four
>   two
>   three

Comment: Added a missing `#include <string>`, and your program [compiles and runs](http://rextester.com/OUUOHM99753) for me. What again seems to be the problem?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik can you explain why it runs correctly on adding this header?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you were using gcc(vc++) compiler and I don't know why it ran perfectly but I use g++11 compiler in my PC and it outputs garbage values.

Comment: The link in first comment was for MSVC. But [it runs with gcc](http://rextester.com/VLJO59328), too. [And clang](http://rextester.com/JYQI86799), for completeness.

Comment: You say you "have encountered an error". What error, exactly? Show the complete error message.

Comment: Here by "error" I meant "undefined behavior". When I run my program it gives garbage output.

Comment: I figured out that it was because of absence of copy constructor in ring class. We would require it as in iterator class constructor it was calling that. But the question then boils down to why did the compiler allow it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik when I remove the reference(&) from m_ring object then it gives error. You seem to have compiled with it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have a very basic doubt that what does it mean to store a reference object in a class. Can you please explain?

Comment: It means an object would have a member that refers to another object. I'm not sure I understand the source of the confusion; it seems pretty straightforward to me.